# Is there a way to get the sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') of the initiating user/schema

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql, oracle12c

Using this function below if I access the table emp from admin1, ideally it should return 0 which would signify the connection user as "ADMIN",  but it return 1( the connection of the end user as its using ADMINT_TEST1.emp)

I want to get the connection identified of ADMIN1 users even when selecting audit_test1.emp
(The function check_user is available in both schemas )
eg :
from admin1 user

```
create or replace function check_user
return number
is
  n number;
begin
  SELECT sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER') into usrname FROM dual;
  if (usrname ='AUDIT_TEST') then
    dbms_output.put_line('show user'||usrname);
    return 1;
  else 
    return 0;
  end if;
end ;
```

Test the function (running from user : ADMIN1)

```
declare
  n number(1);
begin
  select audit_test.check_user into n from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
  select check_user into n from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line(n);
end;
/


Output
===============
show user   AUDIT_TEST
1
show user   ADMIN1
0
```

Is this the expected functionality ? Even though the initiating user is ADMIN1, when we issue admin_test.emp  (the connection_identifier) changes to AUDIT_TEST;

(I have tried best to convey what I  wanted , not sure if the message is clear, please comment if the question is not clear )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simple use `dbms_output.put_line(sys_context('USERENV', 'CURRENT_USER'));` - no need for `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM dual`

Anyway, check [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions199.htm#SQLRF06117):

> `CURRENT_USER`
>
> The name of the database user whose privileges are currently active. This may change during the duration of a database session as Real Application Security sessions are attached or detached, or to reflect the owner of any active definer's rights object. When no definer's rights object is active, CURRENT_USER returns the same value as SESSION_USER.

`CURRENT_USER` is not the current user, it shows the currently active privileges. By default (i.e. definer's rights) inside a Procedure/Function/Package the privileges of the **procedure owner** applies to current user.

In order to get the current user use for this use `sys_context('USERENV', 'SESSION_USER')` or simply `USER`.

Comment: Thank you , SESSION_USER works in this context , helped a lot

Comment: You can simply use `IF USER = 'ADMIN' THEN ...`. However, usually permissions are manged by granting privileges and roles. Typically Oracle does it much better and more reliable than self-developed checks. What do you like to achieve?